# SQL Server Host Name Vs. I.P. Address

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I have already solved my issue, and this question is to understand why the solution worked.  I didn't include code, but can add it if it's needed to answer my question.

I wrote an application in C# to transfer data between different database servers, IE SQL Server to Teradata, Oracle To Teradata. The application would open connection to server A, extract data into a data table, then open a connection to server B and insert the data into the destination table. (Server B is always Teradata) My issue was specific to SQL Server as server A.  For my SQL Server Connection string, I was using DATASOURCE=HOSTNAME\INSTANCENAME along with username/password.  On my laptop, the connection would open with no issues.  Once I compiled my application and ran it from a remote server the connection would timeout. This only occurred with SQL Server connections, and there were multiple servers.  Connections to Oracle and Teradata were fine.  I tried to PING HOSTNAME and PING HOSTNAME\INSTANCENAME for the different SQL Servers, and neither could resolve the host, but when I pinged the IP Address it was able to locate the remote server. I then changed the connection string to IPADDRESS,PORT or IPADDRESS\INSTANCENAME (Where relevant.)  This worked.  My question is WHY?  Why was my laptop able to resolve the host name, but the remote server, also behind corp firewall, was not able to resolve the host until I changed the connection string to an IP Address.

Comment: Which DNS is the SQL Server's hostname defined in, is it a public DNS service?

Comment: It's a private network.  I am working behind a corporate firewall.

Comment: And the hostname is an internal hostname? Try `nslookup hostname` if that does not work speak to your IT support to correct the internal DNS server.